# Leak canary detects some memory leak on detach fragments

Tags: memory-leaks, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel, leakcanary

When I detach fragments from activity, **Leak Canary** detects some memory leaks inside androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView. I have no observable in it and just a viewmodel binded to its databinding object.

```
ApplicationLeak(className=androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView, leakTrace=
┬
.
.
.
│    ↓ MainActivity.controller
├─ com.ncapdevi.fragnav.FragNavController
│    Leaking: NO (ArrayList↓ is not leaking)
│    ↓ FragNavController.rootFragments
├─ java.util.ArrayList
│    Leaking: NO (Object[]↓ is not leaking)
│    ↓ ArrayList.elementData
├─ java.lang.Object[]
│    Leaking: NO (MoreFragment↓ is not leaking)
│    ↓ array Object[].[3]
├─ my.package.name.ui.main.more.MoreFragment
│    Leaking: NO (Fragment#mFragmentManager is not null)
│    Fragment.mTag=my.package.name.ui.main.more.MoreFragment4
│    ↓ MoreFragment.binding
│                   ~~~~~~~
├─ my.package.name.databinding.FragmentMoreBindingImpl
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    ↓ FragmentMoreBindingImpl.mRoot
│                              ~~~~~
╰→ androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
      Leaking: YES (ObjectWatcher was watching this)
      mContext instance of my.package.name.ui.main.MainActivity with mDestroyed = false
      View#mParent is null
      View#mAttachInfo is null (view detached)
      View.mWindowAttachCount = 1
      key = 2262922d-06f8-4abb-ba7b-d276c6fe3082
      watchDurationMillis = 1910
      retainedDurationMillis = -1
, retainedHeapByteSize=7132)
```

Answer (score 2):

MoreFragment is holding on to FragmentMoreBindingImpl (which itself holds NestedScrollView) after onDestroyView. You should clear the reference to the binding in Fragment.onDestroyView()

Comment: How can I do that? I called binding.unbind() _(and for example remove all observables in other fragments)_ but memory leaks exist.

Comment: The javadoc for unbind() says: "Removes binding listeners to expression variables" so that's not it. Try setting MoreFragment.binding = null

Comment: Because of Koltin, binding was not null object, I changed it to null-able  object and one issue was gone. I had another issue with my adapter that was injected by dagger and had a reference to recycler view. I fixed it and now all issues are fixed :D
Thanks.

Comment: Great to hear! If this solved your issue, you can mark it as such ;-)